# sharepoint 2013 get ID of a user

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am looking to figure out a way to get the ID of a user, given their name, so that I can use it in a call to /_layouts/15/userdisp?ID=n where 'n' is the ID of the user to redirect the person who is viewing the page to another person's Profile page.  I am using JavaScript. I will not know the url of the mysites site hence using this method rather than the one using the MySites method.  I am on a search results page not a person search results page.

I am using SharePoint 2013 SP1 April 2015 CU.

Thanks Nigel

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to <strike>do not reinvent the wheel</strike> resolve personal site url from user login name directly instead of constructing the url to display form of User Information list (`/_layouts/15/userdisp?ID=<user id>`).

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve user personal site url:

```
function navigateToPersonalSite()
{

  SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
  SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.userprofiles.js'));
  SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager'], function(){

    getUserProperies(loginName,
       function(properties){
          var url = properties.get_personalUrl();
          window.location.href = url;
       }, 
       function(sender, args) {
          //handle errors...
       }
    );

   });
}   



function getUserProperies(loginName,success,failed)
{
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx);
   var properties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(loginName);
   ctx.load(properties);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
       function(){
          success(properties);
       }, 
      failed);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var loginName = "i:0#.f|membership|jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
navigateToPersonalSite(loginName);
```